# Is there a better approach to get user selection with Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I would like to use window.selection in my **Angular2** project, I try to get the current user selection with a button.

```
<button 
[disabled]="window.getSelection().toString().trim() !=''" 
[ng-click]="selection=window.selection">
Get current selection
</button>
```

I really wonder if it is the better way to do that, is there a better  solution?

Comment: "better" in what way?

Comment: an existing directive to do the same thing without using a native selector